# How to check if std::cin is associated with a terminal or a pipe

Tags: c++, io, cin, istream

How is it possible to check if std::cin buffer is associated with a terminal or a pipe?

Command line which shows that std::cin is associated with a file:

```
Application.exe < C:\output.txt > C:\result.txt
```

Command line which shows std::cin associated with a terminal:

```
Application.exe
```

I tried to analyze in_avail() for this purpose. But it hasn't helped.

```
std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()
```

Comment: Try to [peek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) if there's something to read?

Comment: If there's nothing to read then std::cin waits for an input symbol

Comment: How was `in_avail` unhelpful?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Because it just checks to see if there is anything in the internal buffer.  It doesn't go to the OS.

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer to my question.

First of all I have to ask my question in a correct way.

Question I want to ask: How to figure out if std::cin is associated with a terminal or a pipe.

On Windows:

```
_isatty( _fileno(stdin) );
```

On POSIX:

```
isatty( fileno(stdin) );
```

On Windows:

`_isatty` call retursn non zero value if stdin is associated with a char device.

On POSIX:

`isatty` call returns 1 if stdin is referring to a terminal.

isatty man for Linux: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html

_isatty man on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4s0ddew.aspx

Answer (score 2):

From the [reference of `std::istream::peek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek):

> If `good() == true`, returns the next character as obtained by `rdbuf()->sgetc()` Otherwise, returns `Traits::eof()`.

This means that it will either return the next available character, or an `eof` flag.

And if will, if needed, cause the underlying buffers [`underflow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/underflow) function to be called which fills the buffer if there's anything to read from the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for file input (and user input):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    typedef std::istream::traits_type Traits;
    std::stringstream buffer;
    Traits::int_type ch;
    while((ch = std::cin.get()) != Traits::eof()) {
        buffer << Traits::to_char_type(ch);
    }
    std::cout << buffer.str();
}
```

Having user input in a (linux) terminal a < ctrl-d > is needed to stop reading.

There is no other way (basically), to detect if cin has (will get) a character available (Although some protocol could handle the user input).

Comment: Why can't you just check if the first character is `Traits::eof()`? `bool empty = (std::cin.get() == Traits::eof())`.